# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser: Only Displaying One Div

Tags: php, html, dom, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

On this website [http://roosterteeth.com/](http://roosterteeth.com/home.php) it has a div with the id of 'postsArea'. I am using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to extract the div from the website. The problem I am having is that only one div class's is being displayed, and I can't seem to be able to display all the div classes. I appreciate if anyone can help me as I am totally stuck. below is the code I am using to get the div content.

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');       
$html = file_get_html('http://roosterteeth.com/home.php');
$ret = $html->find('#postsArea', 0);
echo $ret;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this (Works)

```
$html = file_get_html('http://roosterteeth.com/home.php');
foreach ($html->find('div.streamIndividual') as $div) {
    echo $div . '<br />';
};
```

Here `div.streamIndividual`s are child `div`s of `div#postsArea`.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked!!! It's good to have people like you in the community.